# Mongoose pull nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My user schema is

```
{
  widgets: [
    {
      commands: [
        {
          name: 'delete'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  name: 'John',
}
```

and I want to delete widgets.commands by id. I use mongoose. I know the id but when I make the pull request it doesn't delete it.
 `$pull: {widgets.$.commands: {_id: req.params.id}}` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
 update({}, {
     $pull: {
        'widgets.commands._id': req.params.id,
     },
 });
```

---

[$pull mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

***@example from doc***

```
db.profiles.update( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { votes: { $gte: 6 } } } )
```